# Freeware alternative for Chanalyzer?

Tags: linux, wireless-networking

I need to analyze the channel my wifi card is operating on. I have found a program called Chanalyzer Pro, offered by [metageek](http://www.metageek.net/products/chanalyzer-pro/). However, it is not really worth it for me to buy the software if I will only use it one time. Does anyone know of any freeware alternatives, preferably for Linux?

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While iwlist does show signal level, it does not show noise and other information which the spectrum analysis tool shows. I have discovered a program called [Horst](http://br1.einfach.org/tech/horst/) which is a simple channel analyzer, not as detailed as the commercial ones, but it does its job.

Apparently, [Kismet](https://kismetwireless.net/spectools/) also has this capability through plug-ins. I will have to try that a bit later, when I get the time.

Comment: IWLIST does show the noise level for me, on the same line as the signal and quality.  A quick and dirty command "iwlist eth1 scanning | egrep "ESSID|Noise" shows this.  Horste does look pretty cool though - it seems to merge the output from ISLIST (or equivalent) and TCPDUMP (or equivalent)

Comment: @davidgo  

$ iwlist wlan1 scanning | egrep "ESSID|Noise"  

only shows the name of the ESSID for me

Answer (score 2):

If you have an Android device, grab Wifi Analyzer - its free and really good for showing whats going on with WIFI - and portable too.

Most Linux WIFI connection programs should show you usefull "dumbed down" information, but you can see exactly what the signal strengths are by (from a terminal) typing

```
iwlist WLANDEV scanning  | less
```

This will show you all the broadcasting ESSID's and quality, signal strength, noise level, security, mode, supported bit rates, Mac addresses - only its not very pretty.